# Phalcon Incubator not loading translation namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, phalcon

I have have added the composer require:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phalcon/incubator": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

I've added the location to the Phalcon loader file (is this correct?):

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

/**
 * We're a registering a set of directories taken from the configuration file
 */
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Phalcon' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/phalcon/incubator/Library/Phalcon/',
    'APPNAME\Models' => $config->application->modelsDir,
    'APPNAME\Controllers' => $config->application->controllersDir,
    'APPNAME\Forms' => $config->application->formsDir,
    'APPNAME' => $config->application->libraryDir
));

$loader->register();
```

Then I have this in my controller:

```
$translate = new Phalcon\Translate\Adapter\Gettext(array(
            'locale' => 'en_GB',
            'file' => 'messages',
            'directory' => '../app/lang'
));
```

But I get the following error:
[image]

Why isn't it loading the Incubator files?

Thanks
Nathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use FQCN when you are not including namespaces using the `use` keyword: (not the first `\` in the FQCN)

```
$translate = new \Phalcon\Translate\Adapter\Gettext(array(
        'locale' => 'en_GB',
        'file' => 'messages',
        'directory' => '../app/lang'
));
```

If you don't do this, the namespace is assumed to be relative to the current namespace (which is defined by the `namespace` statement at the top of the file)

---

Btw, you don't need to configure the Phalcon autoloading, composer takes care of the autoloading of Phalcon for you. I would also recommend using Composer's autoloader instead of both Composer's and phalcon's loaders.